# trying to find documentation on ruby's trailing if usage

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working in the RSpec book (page 121) and am being presented with a bit of code that is apparently self evident and clear.  It's not self evident for me, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand.

I'm coming to ruby from c# so please use small words :)

Here's the original code

```
def total_match_count
    count = 0
    secret = @secret.split('')
    @guess.split('').map do |n|
        if secret.include?(n)
            secret.delete_at(secret.index(n))
            count += 1
        end
    end
    count
end
```

here's the refactor

```
def total_match_count
    secret = @secret.split('')
    @guess.split('').inject(0) do |count, n|
        count + (delete_first(secret, n) ? 1 : 0)
    end
end

def delete_first(code, n)
    code.delete_at(code.index(n)) if code.index(n)
end
```

Again, this is supposed to be so obvious as to need no comment.
I'm not understanding the trailing "if code.index(n)" bit and I can't find any documentation on using the keywords "ruby trailing if"

Obviously I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby Post-Conditions as Syntactic Sugar

In Ruby, almost everything is an expression, and keywords like `if` and `unless` can be used as [expression modifiers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Modifier+if+and+unless) that *follow* an expression. Some languages refer to these as post-conditions, but the general idea is that:

```
if 1 == 1
  puts true
end
```

is intended to be equivalent to:

```
puts true if 1 == 1
```

The post-condition can sometimes make the intent of the code clearer, or create a more natural flow. The parser differentiates between the :if and :if_mod tokens that internally represent the "normal" if-statement and its matching post-condition, but from a programmer's perspective the post-conditions are (or should be) largely syntactic sugar to make certain expressions easier or cleaner to read and write.

You don't ever *need* post-conditions in Ruby, but you will often find them in idiomatic Ruby code. If you don't grok them, or don't find that they improve the readability of your code, then feel free to ignore them until and unless they seem useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm digging into the Ruby on Rails tutorial, but it looks like I may need to deep dive on ruby as well.

I can see this syntax as being much more readable.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
code.delete_at(code.index(n)) if code.index(n)
```

is the same as this:

```
if code.index(n)
  code.delete_at(code.index(n))
end
```

Some people think the one-liner is easier to read. It's a matter of style--when lines become long, the "trailing if" can be a gotcha, as you might not think to read to the end of the line to realize it has a condition attached. Use judiciously.

Ruby also has `unless`, which can be used in the "trailing" form too:

```
do_stuff unless no_on_second_thought
```

Comment: Thanks - love the unless psudo-code.

Can you explain what code.index(n) is even doing in this example?

Comment: It seems like we're using a non-zero return from "code.index(n)" as a bool of "true"

Is that correct?

Comment: `code.index(n)` returns `nil` when the array index is out of range, and Ruby treats `nil` as `false` in conditional expressions. Note that `nil` and `false` are *not* equivalent. In Ruby everything (almost) is an object, so `nil` is an instance of `NilClass` and `false` is an instance of `FalseClass`. It is idiomatic to return `nil` as a safe (non-exceptional) value to indicate failure, a missing value, etc.