# How do print odd numbers using block { }

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print my array with just odd numbers using the block method but i am not too sure how to.

I can print odd numbers using no block but do but do not know how to implement it into the block method {  }

```
#non block method

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

array.each do |i|
  if i % 2 == 0
    puts "#{i}"
  end
end

#output of 2 4 6 8
```

```
#block method not sure how

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

array.each {|i| put i if i % 2 == 0 end }

#expected output should be 2 4 6 8
```

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: 2, 4, 6 and 8 are the _even_ elements.

Comment: yeah my block method wasn't fully completed Mshka solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your block is almost correct you just need to remove the `end` as it's [an inline (or trailing) if method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859271/5872935), you also need to use `puts` and not `put`

```rb
array.each {|i| puts i if i % 2 == 0 }
```

also, note that ruby has a `.even?` and `.odd?` methods you can call on integers

```rb
array.each {|i| puts i if i.odd? }
```

Comment: There's no `pair?` method – do you mean `even?`

Comment: @Stefan yeah you're right, it's even, updated answer, thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#select-method) the [`even?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Integer.html#even-3F-method) elements and print them afterwards:

```
array.select(&:even?).each { |i| puts i }
```

Or alternatively via [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#reject-method) and [`odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Integer.html#odd-3F-method):

```
array.reject(&:odd?).each { |i| puts i }
```

The `each` call isn't really needed, as you can pass an entire array to `puts` and it will print each element on a separate line:

```
puts array.select(&:even?)

# or

puts array.reject(&:odd?)
```

All of the above will generate the same output:

```
2
4
6
8
```